# what idea should i use for this application iOS -json and local notification

Tags: ios, json, notifications

hello all I'm asking if any one can help me what i should use for this idea

I'm developing  iPhone 5 application this application for movies it's like reminder

i create php script can accept  post request from iPhone and save the data in mysql , 
also there is another page on the script for display user movies .

**i want my application every 1 minutes call the newMovies.php page and check return data( json)
if json key"New":"true"
the application will send local notification .**

all this task on the background pls i need advice for this application .

Answer (score 0):

if any one looking for same question , i will answer

finally i used , Timer on applicationDidEnterBackground

this timer will call selector (method)

and the selector will check if there is any things new and pus local notification .